# Error Inner exception: The value assigned to property 'DateTime' is not valid: '24/02/2015 17:24:05'

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I use BizTalk 2010 and when my orchestration prepare my message to send it to WCF service with my dynamic port send-receive I get this error:

```
Exception thrown from: segment 3, progress 6
Inner exception: The value assigned to property 'myDateTime' is not valid: '24/02/2015 17:24:05'.

Exception type: InvalidPropertyValueException
Source: ###
Target Site: Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.StopConditions segment3(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.StopConditions)
```

DATA:

```
<ns0:mydatetime>2015-02-24T18:24:05</ns0:mydatetime>
```

Comment: Rather than comment, click the 'edit' link under the question tags and directly fix your question.  I've done it for you here, but it works best if you handle updates yourself in the future.  Be sure to format XML as code else the tags won't show.  Thanks.

Comment: Is myDateTime a variable in your code?  If so show us the code.

Comment: i have a send-receive port to send a msg; and mydatetime in this msg;  i tried to change mydatetime  to string but i had the same error

Comment: Without the code we sample we don't know what you are trying and can't really help you.

Comment: What is the XSD datatype of mydatetime?

Comment: DateTime and it is promed in property schema

Comment: Well the myDateTime in the error not in the correct format for a XSD datetime, the one you show in DATA is although it missing a time zone and differs by an hour.  So the issue is whatever is doing the assignment to the promoted field. But as you haven't given us that code we can't tell you exactly what you have done wrong.

Comment: i get the problem; we must update schema in Biztalk no just GAC it , Gac it is not enought, biztalk take a previous version (from DB biztalkmgmtdb) if you  updated your schema